# Jquery Accordion choosing correct selector

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm struggling with plugging in the correct selector into jquery. When I plug in ".accordionButton" the entire div is clickable and the functionality works great. However, I want to make only the "h3.toggle a" clickable, but plugging that selector in doesn't work. Is there something else in the jquery I need to change here? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The HTML:

```
<div class="accordionButton">

<div class="case-top">
<div class="case-left"></div>

<div class="case-right">
<h3 class="toggle"><a href="#one">Our Strategy and Results</a></h3>
 </div>

</div><!--end case-top-->
</div><!--end button-->

<div class="accordionContent">sliding content here</div>
```

The JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.accordionButton h3.toggle a').click(function() {

//REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
$('.accordionButton h3.toggle a').removeClass('on');

//NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
$('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

//IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

//ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
$(this).addClass('on');

//OPEN THE SLIDE
$(this).next().slideDown('normal');
} 
});
/*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/
//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.accordionButton h3.toggle a').mouseover(function() {
$(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {

$(this).removeClass('over');                                
});
$('.accordionContent').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
$(this)
```

but you change the selector, you need to change all $(this) selectors to

```
$('.accordionButton')
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/VmWSN/)**

Comment: I changed all the instances and the button is toggling the panels, but it is toggling all of the panels now, and applying the instances to all the .accordionButton buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is where I'm at... the buttons are now working correctly, but on click all the  instances of .accordionContent open, not just next one. ( FYI, I removed the mouseover from this code snipped)

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.accordionButton h3.toggle a').click(function() {

//REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
$('.accordionButton h3.toggle a').removeClass('on');

//NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
$('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

//IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
if($('.accordionButton').next().is(':hidden') == true) {

//ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON (correct)
$(this).addClass('on');

//OPEN THE SLIDE
$('.accordionButton').next().slideDown('normal');
} 
});
```

I'm guessing the lines:

```
$('.accordionButton').next().slideDown('normal');
```

and

```
if($('.accordionButton').next().is(':hidden') == true) {
```

are the lines which need editing. I need these two lines to open and close just the "next" .accordionContent instances not all of the instances together.